# Return blank value on graph when datasource is empty in excel

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have an excel file which calculate a person's monthly score/grade. My problem is, I don't want excel chart to return "0" value on chart whenever my datasource cell is blank. Is it possible ?. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found in google several ways to do it, I don't know it they may help you, you didn't put your excel version.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/14040-how-not-graph-blank-cells.html
http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/373761-excel-dont-chart-zero-values.html